# How to add Event with Dynamic Radio Buttons to show a Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a dynamic online survey form in laravel 8. In some questions I have Radio Buttons with Text Box in case of Other Options.

[image: Options with Text Box]

I am generating these questions from a database.

```
@case(1)
     <input type="radio" name="{{ $property->name }}" value="" hidden checked>
         @foreach ($property->options as $option)
             <input id="{{ $option->option }}" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" type="radio" name="{{ $property->name }}" value="{{ $option->option }}"
              {{ old($property->name) == $option->option ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                   {{ $option->option }}</br>
                
                 @endforeach
                     <div id="dvtext" style="display: block">
                           <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
                      </div>
```

You can see in code, $property is a question and $option are associated options of each question. I have more than 10 question of similar nature. It means coming out of database dynamically. Can you please help me in:

1. How can add a behavior that, if somebody click on Other (radio button option) on any question, then text box should appear but only on that question.
2. OR If I keep text box visible all the time and click on text box, automatically Other option (radio button) should be selected/checked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your radio button is `checked` first see if the value is `Other` or not depending on this `show()` or `hide()` your div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  //check if radio is checked and value of checked one is `others`
  ($(this).val() == "Other") ? $(this).siblings(".dvtext").show(): $(this).siblings(".dvtext").hide()
})
```

```css
.dvtext {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--give outer divs to seprate-->
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="" hidden checked>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="somethings">somethings <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="Other">Other
  <!--use class-->
  <div class="dvtext">
    <input type="text" class="txtBox" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="2" value="" hidden checked>
  <input type="radio" name="2" value="somethings">somethings <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="2" value="Other">Other
  <!--use class here-->
  <div class="dvtext">
    <input type="text" class="txtBox" />
  </div>
</div>
```